# Getting the time complexity

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I wrote this algorithm. Can you help me calculate 'the time complexity' ?
I don't have nested function, but have .includes inside map.

```
function prime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) if (num % i === 0) return false;
  return num > 1;
}

const function = (dataA, dataB) => {
  let temp = {};
  let tempArray = [];
  dataB.forEach(function (x) {
    temp[x] = (temp[x] || 0) + 1;
  });
  dataA.map(item => {
    if (dataB.includes(item) && !prime(temp[item])) {
      tempArray.push(item);
    } else if (!dataB.includes(item)) {
      tempArray.push(item);
    }
  });
  return tempArray;
};

console.log('Input A:', A);
console.log('Input B:', B);
console.log('Output:', function(A, B));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations:

- `B.includes` has a time complexity of O(`B.length`)
- `isPrime` has a time complexity of O(`num`). Since the argument is the frequency of a value in B, it is bounded by the size of B, and so it has a worst case of O(`B.length`), as `isPrime` is only called when `B.includes` is called, it is thus irrelevant for the overall time complexity.
- As `B.includes` is called as many times as there are values in A, the overall time complexity is O(`A.length * B.length`)

The complexity can be reduced by replacing `B.includes(item)` with `count[item]`, and then `isPrime` becomes determining. If `isPrime` is extended with memoization, the total cost of all `isPrime` calls together is O(`A.length + B.length`), so then that is also the overall time complexity.

This cannot be further reduced, as even without a call to `isPrime`, the iteration over both input arrays is necessary and already represents that time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isPrime` function has a worst-case time complexity of O(n).

The `forEach` function is a separate O(n) function.

The `map` function that evaluates each item in `dataA` and does O(n) in each of `includes` and `isPrime` function.

So, the total time complexity is O(n^2).